# How highly available is the master zone of my GKE cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

GKE seems to create a cluster using one availability zone for the master although it provides an option to deploy nodes to multiple availability zones. I am concerned that if master AZ goes down, I cannot manage my cluster anymore. I understand my apps will continue to run but it is a big concern that I cannot scale up my service or deploy a new version of my apps, etc.

Is my understanding of "GKE cluster is vulnerable to master zone going down" correct? If not, can you please explain how? If it is correct, what are my options to make it highly available so that it can tolerate one availability zone going down?

Answer (score 3):

The GKE master today is not highly available and if a zone goes down, your cluster's Kubernetes API will go down with it. However you should note that GKE master is managed service with a 99.5% SLA. https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/sla In the future, GKE may offer high-availability solutions for the master (API server).

Your understanding is correct that if the Kubernetes master/API becomes unavailable for a brief amount of time, it does not impact your deployed workloads (e.g. websites or other services) running on the cluster. But you will not be able to scale up/down things.

As a user, you cannot do anything to make the master highly available today.

However, I would say 99.5% is a pretty good uptime. It corresponds to 7 minutes a day (https://uptime.is/99.5) and if you are not managing your cluster 24/7, you are likely to see issues every now and then. If you are using automation, you should probably have some retry logic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Ahmet. Unfortunately 99.5% SLA is not sufficient for me. Can **kubernetes federation** be my answer to achieving 99.9% and higher availability? I consider deploying multiple cluster; one per availability zone and use federation across.

Comment: Currently, **Cluster Federation** means that you're setting up the management plane for federation yourself, in a single cluster. Therefore it's probably not going to be very different than the hosted GKE option. What I can suggest is, look at `kubeadm` tool to create your cluster manually on GCE with multiple masters.

Comment: Yes, I understand that one of the clusters hosts the federation plane and if the corresponding AZ goes down for that cluster, you lose the federation. However what I like about it is that other clusters are still available individually.

Comment: When the federation plane recovers, would it discover the changes I made to the other cluster? For instance, assume a federation with clusters A and B. Cluster A hosts the federation. I have a pod deployment with 4 replicas; cluster A and B gets 2 each. When cluster A goes down, hence federation plane goes down, if I increase the replica count on Cluster B to 4 to compensate for the loss of cluster A, what happens when federation comes back up? Would it overwrite cluster B back to 2 replicas?

Comment: You're going off-topic from the question. Once you set up the federation you should control things via the federation, not individual clusters.

Comment: Thanks, Ahmet. I asked the same as a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446275/does-kubernetes-federation-rebalance-pods-across-clusters-after-it-recovers-from

Comment: Regional clusters are now GA, which solves this problem.

Answer (score 3):

GKE [regional clusters](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/regional-clusters), which offer a multi-master setup with one master in each zone in the region, are now generally available.  See the [launch blog post](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/with-google-kubernetes-engine-regional-clusters-master-nodes-are-now-highly-available) for a quick overview.