# Does Kubernetes Federation rebalance pods across clusters after it recovers from outage?

Tags: kubernetes, federation, google-cloud-platform

When the federation plane recovers from a zone outage, would it discover the changes I made to the other cluster? For instance, assume a federation with clusters A and B. Cluster A hosts the federation. I have a pod deployment with 4 replicas; cluster A and B gets 2 each. When cluster A goes down, hence federation plane goes down, if I increase the replica count on Cluster B to 4 to compensate for the loss of cluster A, what happens when federation comes back up? Would it overwrite cluster B back to 2 replicas?

Comment: possibly related: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/33312

Comment: also see: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/0f95f13dcca23302d973a923fba6bc95fc502a7c/federation/pkg/federation-controller/deployment/deploymentcontroller.go and https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/8ef6857881641cc04132b78a6b052be3b708d715/federation/pkg/federation-controller/util/planner/planner.go